# Meteor: How to prevent client from accessing methods

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, methods, meteor

All meteor methods can be called same way from client and server side.

Let's say user knows or can predict all the method names on server, then he is able to call them and use it's result however he want.

example:
A method which performs cross domain http request and return response can be used to overload server by calling huge amounts of data `Meteor.call(httpLoad, "google.com");`, or a method which load data from mongo can be used to access database documents if the client know document _id `Meteor.call(getUserData, "_jh9d3nd9sn3js");`.

So, how to avoid this situations, may be there is a better way to store server-only functions than in `Meteor.methods({...})`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Meteor methods are designed to be accessed from the client, if you don't want this, you just need to define a normal javascript function on the server. A really basic example would be:

`server/server.js`:

```
someFunction = function(params) {
    console.log('hello');
}
```

As long as it's in the server folder, the function won't be accessible from the client.

---

For coffeescript users, each file is technically a separate scope, so you would have to define a global variable with `@`, e.g.

```
@someFunction = (params) ->
    console.log 'hello'
```

or if you want to scope the function to a package:

```
share.someFunction = (params) ->
    console.log 'hello'
```

---

If you have methods that need to be accessible from the client but only for say admin users, you need to add those checks at the start of the meteor method definition:

```
Meteor.methods({
    'someMethod': function(params) {
        var user = Meteor.user();
        if (user && (user.isAdmin === true)) {
            // Do something
        } else {
            throw new Meteor.Error(403, 'Forbidden');
        }
    }
});
```

I'm not going to vouch for the security of this example - it's just that, an example - but hopefully it gives you some idea of how you would secure your methods.

EDIT: Noticed the other answers mention using a `if (Meteor.isServer) { ... }` conditional. Note that if you are doing this *inside* methods which are also accessible on the client, the user will be still be able to see your server code, even if they can't run it. This may or may not be a security problem for you - basically be careful if you're hardcoding any 3rd-party API credentials or any kind of sensitive data in methods whose code can be accessed from the client. If you don't need the method on the client, it would be better to just use normal JS functions. If you're *wrapping* the whole Meteor.methods call with a isServer conditional, the code will be on the server only, but can still be called from the client.

Comment: Meteor methods can be chained easily with callbacks, which probably will not work for regular functions because of "Code must run within fibers". So far that is the best answer anyway ;)

Comment: Depends what you're trying to achieve. As far as I know, if you use method callbacks on the server then you'll just get 'undefined' returned. The rest of the method will run but you wont get the result returned. If you need something to be returned then you need to run the method synchronously (e.g. without a callback), so it will return a value or throw an error.

Answer (score 4):

as rightly stated in other answers, your methods will always be accessible from the client (per design). yet, there is a simple workaround to check if the call originates from the client or from the server. if you do a

```
if ( this.connection == null )
```

this will `return true` if the method was called from server. like that you can restrict the method body execution to 'secure' calls.

Comment: I would then wrap whatever is inside `if(this.connection == null)` with `if(Meteor.isServer)` to prevent client simulation and console errors.

Comment: I've tried this method twice now and both times whenever a Meteor method is called by server code - it still passes the client connection to it.  For example if I call `Meteor.call('sendMail', ...)` in `Accounts.onCreateUser` which is only in my `server` folder, it passes a live connection to the Meteor method.  I've noticed other Meteor methods do the same thing when trying to call "server only" Meteor methods.  The only time there's no connection is when I try calling it from the Meteor shell.  Any ideas?

Comment: yes. if the call originated on the client `this.connection` will not be `undefined`. check this out for more info about it:  http://themeteorchef.com/recipes/building-a-saas-with-meteor-stripe-part-1/#tmc-a-wee-bit-of-controversy

Comment: Got it! Thanks for the link. The main reason I was wanting to make server-only Meteor methods is they can be called asynchronously which is useful to unblock synchronous-only methods like `Email.send()` which will block your client. So a solution I found to call certain synchronous methods asynchronously is to just wrap them in a `Meteor.setTimeout` set for any time later. This will remove the call from the event queue and allow the client to continue. Works great if you don't need the function called right away (e.g. sending emails).

Comment: true that, there is a wrapper around `Meter.setTimeout` with delay 0, that will do exactly what you say: remove it from the event queue. it's called `Meteor.defer()`. just in case you haven't stumbled upon it yet..

Comment: Nice. Indeed I haven't found that.  And it's not in the doc.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think this page explains it: http://meteortips.com/first-meteor-tutorial/methods/

I'm quoting:

"The safer approach is to move these functions to the isServer conditional, which means:

Database code will execute within the trusted environment of the server.
Users won’t be able to use these functions from inside the Console, since users don’t have direct access to the server.

Inside the isServer conditional, write the following:

```
Meteor.methods({
   // methods go here
});
```

This is the block of code we’ll use to create our methods."

and so on. I hope this helps.

Comment: "Users won’t be able to use these functions from inside the Console", sorry to say that, but... they will be able. http://www.evernote.com/shard/s244/sh/a96eb058-8b6e-4f71-85b0-2b400a392914/5e035ce99ed78b0ed5b90cddc8e33827

Comment: Oops, then the page must be mistaken, sorry!

Comment: You are both right, all the isServer wrapper does is define the method only on the server, so you wouldn't be able to read the code of the method, but you can still execute it from the client, with the result returned from the server. The reason you might define a method on the client is for optimistic UI, so you can run a simplified version of the method on the client and immediately update the UI/minimongo, but then the server would return the REAL result, and if it doesn't match, minimongo / the UI would be updated to reflect that.

Comment: that's interesting, sounds like programming online games, where player get instant reaction in game, and then his calculations are eventually corrected by server result.

Answer (score 0):

With proper app design, you shouldn't care whether a request was through the web UI or via something typed in a console window.

Basically, don't put generic, abuse worthy functions in Meteor.methods, implement reasonable access controls, and rate-limit and/or log anything that could be a problem.

Any server-side function defined in Meteor.methods will have access to the current user id through [`this.userid`](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/method_userId).  This userid is supplied by Meteor, not a client API parameter.

Since that Meteor Method server-side code knows the login status and userid, it can then do all the checking and rate limiting you want before deciding to do that thing that the user asked it to do.

How do you rate limit?  I've not looked for a module for this lately. In basic Meteor you would add a Mongo collection for user actions accessible server-side only. Insert timestamped, userid specific data on every request that arrives via a Meteor method.  Before fulfilling a request in the server method code, do a Mongo find for how many such actions occurred from this userid in a relevant period.  This is a little work and will generates some overhead, but the alternative of rate-limiting via a server-wide underscore-style debounce leaves a function open for both abuse and denial-of-service by an attacker.

Comment: Haven't tested it yet but meteorhacks:sikka is a rate-limiter for meteor methods (see https://atmospherejs.com/meteorhacks/sikka). I think I read somewhere that they were going to implement something similar as part of the meteor core but I'm not sure if/when that would be.